# Converting 0 to 360 raster climate data to -180 to 180 data in R issues with Rotate()

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, r-raster, coordinate-transformation, terra

I am new to R and I am working with a raster brick of climate data. To preform my analysis I need to convert it from the 0-360 lat/lon format it is currently in to the standard 180 to -180. From looking around it seems that the way to do this is with rotate() however this function is not working for me.

I only need the area of Europe and my laptop cannot handle the full global data set with all the layers. So I have a map that looks like this after I cropped out just Europe.

[image: Current data]

The data looks like this

```
PRE_e <- brick("/Cropped/Europe/trimmed_to_RH/Units/pre_mm_m.nc") 
PRE_e
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 19, 192, 3648, 94181  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1.875, 1.864677  (x, y)
#extent     : -0.9375, 359.0625, 35.42887, 70.85773  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : pre_mm_m.nc
```

to rotate the data I used the below, but I get an error:

```
x1 <- rotate(PRE_e, "Results/Test_rotate_PRE.tif", left = FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
#Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Unable to create dataset
#In addition: Warning message:
#In .rasterFromRasterFile(grdfile, band = band, objecttype, ...) :
#  size of values file does not match the number of cells (given the #data type)
```

Any suggestions would be amazing thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
a <- PRE_e * 1
```

And can you try the below (without the filename argument (because the error message suggests that the "./Results" folder does not exist

```
x1 <- rotate(PRE_e, left = FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
```

And did you try this with "terra"?

```
library(terra)
p <- rast("/Cropped/Europe/trimmed_to_RH/Units/pre_mm_m.nc") 
r <- rotate(p, "Results/Test_rotate_PRE.tif", left = FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Perhaps the solution is to first use `rotate`, and then `crop` out the area of interest. I also wonder how you cropped the original data, because it does not look like you did that (at least not with R).